# Create a condition in an OnEdit function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, conditional-statements

I have the following onEdit function

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  const range = sheet.getRange('D2:D'); 
  
  range.createTextFinder('[^0-9]').useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith(');
```

It removes all characters (text and special) from the cell, leaving only the numbers.

However, I would like it to be executed only if Column B says “after x hours”.

For example:

Cell B2 is equal to “após x horas”, so I want the above function to be executed in cell D2, when I enter something in it — that is, if I paste some data into D2, all characters will be removed, just sticking the numbers, because B2 is “após x horas”.

Cell B3 is equal to “7 dias ”, so the function should not be executed — that is, when I write something in cell D3, the characters CANNOT be removed.

[image]

How to do this?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Cell B2 is equal to “após x horas”, so I want the above function to be executed in cell D2, when I enter something in it — that is, if I paste some data into D2, all characters will be removed, just sticking the numbers, because B2 is “após x horas”. Cell B3 is equal to “7 dias ”, so the function should not be executed — that is, when I write something in cell D3, the characters CANNOT be removed.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: I usually paste information into column D and the function removes the characters just leaving the numbers. e.g. : if I paste the phrase “72 hours”, automatically the word 'hours' is removed. Just getting number 72.

I wanted this function to be executed from a criterion. The function would only remove the characters and leave the numbers, if in column B the text 'after x hours' is written.

Did you understand?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood that you want to remove the text characters from the cells of column "D". But, I cannot understand `I wanted this function to be executed from a criterion. The function would only remove the characters and leave the numbers, if in column B the text 'after x hours' is written.`. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. But, I would like to support you. So, can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: In your sample Spreadsheet, when "B2" is `após x horas`, why `44` is put into the cell "D2"? And, when "B3" is `7 dias`, why the cell "D3" is empty? I thought that when I could correctly understand your expected logic, I can think of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the two conditions and execute the replace action only when the conditions are met:

- B2 = 'apox...'
- B3 != '7 dias'

So your code should be like this:

```
let first_condition = "após x horas"
let second_condition = "7 dias"

function onEdit(e) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  const range = sheet.getRange('D2:D'); 

  if (sheet.getRange('B2:B2').getValues()[0][0].trim() == first_condition
       && sheet.getRange('B3:B3').getValues()[0][0].trim() !== second_condition) {
    
    range.createTextFinder('[^0-9]').useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith('');
    console.log("Cleaning out non valid characters")
  }
  else {
    console.log("Skipping the cleaning process")
  }

}
```

You probably need to adjust the conditions and I suggest to remove the logs.